# How to define category ID in an array?

Tags: categories, array, include, exclude, id

I have the following:

```
<?php if ( array( 'is_category', 'is_tag' ) ) { ?>
```

What I want to do is (that doesn't quite work):

```
<?php if ( array( 'is_category('13')', 'is_tag' ) ) { ?>
```

So what I'm asking is, how can I include that ID in code that will work? That's how I would do it anywhere outside of an array, so I am unsure exactly how to include it here.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do.

Comment: Now you're just checking whether the array is not empty. The whole `array(...)` part is converted to a boolean. Your current `if` statement will always return `true`.

Comment: @Chris_O & all: Fellas, this question is simple as well as easily answerable by googling. Fair enuff, the OP could have put more effort into it. Also his understanding of PHP is (yet) rather basic, obviously. Nonetheless, why answer it in the comments? Not only do you cheat yourself of possible rep, it undermines SE site mechanics. That's just not good practice, IMHO. See [meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/857/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-have-an-answer-in-the-question-comments)

Comment: Point taken... comment deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Geert pointed out, your current conditional will always be true.
An [if()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) construct needs to be fed an [expression](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).
You're feeding it a valid array, so that's *true*. Always.
So far this is basic PHP, regardless of whether in a WP environment or not.

As can be read in Chris_O's comment

```
if ( is_category('some-cat') && is_tag('some-tag') ) {
    // do something
}
```

will do the trick.

`'some-cat'` and `'some-tag'` may be the category/tag slug, id or title.
The codex page on [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) explains the use of these rather well.

Comment: I've finished reading a section of that page and it's helped a lot, thank you